# How do you run a VTSO Word project in the same solution as the start-up project during run-time and pass variables to the content controls?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, vsto

In short I  want to pass variables to a vsto project from my windows form project and I don't know how.

I currently have a windows forms project that is near completion with one major piece missing. I have been searching for about two work days for a way to open a VTSO word project in the same solution with a procedure in my windows form project. I know I can code my project to open the word document and my code for default values for the content controls in the "ThisDocument.vb" display correctly. I have added references to my VTSO project to refer to my forms project in an attempt to use variables previously collected to fill in my content controls text, but I have no clue how to do this. Will I have to open the word document and use interops to modify the document separately? I would prefer my answer in VB.Net but if C# is what ya know, I'll take anything to help.

Comment: Hi @Ave_Dog08 I'm not sure I completely understand your question but generally VSTO is tied with the host application (Word, Excel, Outlook ..)
So if you're aiming to use your Form project to open a Word document via VSTO then yes, the Word document must be opened. You may consider using [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456488.aspx) where you can read/write a document without opening the document

Comment: I guess in short, I just want to pass variables to a vsto project from my windows form project.

Comment: I think I'll just load the data into a temp table and have it pull in the values upon opening.